# java/javac -version command reponse with nothing

Tags: java, bash, command-line, environment-variables

First, I'm using CentOS v6.1

I installed openjdk 8 and extracted it.
I set `$JAVA_HOME`, `$JRE_HOME $PATH` in `~/.bash_profile` like below.

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/home/software/jdk8u222-b10
export JRE_HOME=/home/software/jdk8u222-b10/jre
```

I've also used source `~/.bash_profile` in command line.

But when I type `$ /home/software/jdk8u222-b10/bin/java -version or java -version`,

it shows nothing to me even 'not found' errors. => [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1OM7.png)

How can I solve this problem?

---

I think it is not an environment path problem

When I directly execute jdk/bin/java file, it shows nothing to me.

Comment: what happens when you run `which java` or plain `java`?

Comment: and whats the output when you run `java`?

Comment: which java prints '~/software/jdk8u222-b10/bin/java'

Comment: and no output from java command

Comment: so some issue with your JVM. wither its not properly installed or have some dependency issue.

Comment: I've changed it into latest version but it still does not work
and same jdk working very well in another server

Comment: You say that `jdk/bin/java` does not output anything. What does the command `file jdk/bin/java` say? And why are you testing jdk/bin, when your Java lives in `~/software/jdk8u222-b10/bin`?

Comment: Yes, jdk/bin/java means ~/software/jdk8u222-b10/bin/java executable file.

Comment: Why I'm testing jdk/bin is java command didn't work in apache tomcat and I followed the problems. And I knew that java executable does not respond.

Answer (score -1):

It was server-side problem.

Old version of glibc and java was conflicted.

After upgrade glibc, the conflict did not occurred.